# How to show certain activity only 3 times in android?

Tags: java, javascript, android

Hi I wanted to show one activity only 3 times in android. Actually its a dialog which ask user some suggestion if user rejects it more than 3 times that dialog will not appear again unless and until user uninstall and reinstall the app.

Can anybody suggest me some solution to this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show some code please, we can't help atm.

Comment: manage it with a shared preference may be it will work

Answer (score 1):

This is for conditional display of dialog. I had performed a similar functionality earlier. You can do so by having a counting variable in the `sqlite`. Each time the user rejects the dialog for suggestion, fetch the entry from the database, check if it is less than or equal to 3. If less than 3, then display the dialog, update the database entry by incrementing count variable by 1. Otherwise, if more than 3, do not display the dialog.

Creating a database and initializing the variable:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("MYDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTbl(Name VARCHAR,num VARCHAR);");
//Here, Name is the name of your counting variable and num is the value you want to store in it

String name="count";
String num="0";

String s="INSERT INTO myTbl VALUES ('"+name+"','"+num+"');";
db.execSQL(s);
Log.d("myapp", "Insertion of data successfull");
db.close();
```

The advantage of using this approach is that, once the application is uninstalled, its corresponding `sqlite` database will also be deleted. Hence, this will ensure that if the user ignore the dialog for more than 3 times, then the dialog will not launch as long as the application is uninstalled and reinstalled. Regarding updating the values in sqlite, i hope you know the basics.

Hope this has helped

Answer (score 0):

Create a SharedPreferances save 0 as initial value in it, on user rejection, increment the value by 1 and save it in SharedPreferances, once the value reaches to 3, don’t start the activity again. You can use database instead of sharedPreferances.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SharedPreferances for counting the value of showing suggestion like 0 to 3. For the suggestion show you can use separate layout and use include it to your main layout. Then the complexity of activity handling will be reduced. When the layout is showed three times then the specific layout should not be shown by setting it's visibility GONE.